# Extended Search

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I've got a big text file which looks like the following:

```
text;text;text;text;text - 5 words
text;text;text;text;text;text - 6 words
text;text;text;text;text;text;text - 7 words
```

How i can search lines with 6, 7,... words?

I try search with `(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);` but not work :(

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Notepad++ does choke on my existing regex, but the OP adapted it to suit his need, see the comments for more.*

First of all, you should be doing a regular expression search, not an extended search.

Here's the regex. Basically you match the first 5 words, then match at least one more after the first 5 (if you don't need to match the last semicolon, take out the `;?`):

```
(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*)(;(.*))+;?
```

(You cannot use `(.*)(;(.*)){5,}` as Notepad++ doesn't support that syntax.)

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the hint. No need for my answer, then.

Comment: Oh how curious, Notepad++ seems to be hopelessly confused by the last bit. Hang on while I edit my answer..

Comment: @Jam: Does it work for you? My Notepad++ seems to choke on the last bit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't abuse the *. If you are trying to match at least one character, .+ is less ambiguous. In fact, if ; is the separator, you can try [^;]+ to be even more pedantic.